# Running ROS on Digital Ocean?

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz

Has anyone done this? Create a "droplet" or whatever they call it and set up ROS, and be able to actually run roscore, gazebo, rviz, etc. from there?

I can imagine various complications, like having a static IP, figuring out what to with graphics apps like gazebo. Is there any way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did install a YARP based environment on my droplet along with graphics and it works great. I use it for testing purpose.

The installation in my case was very standard and when it came to graphics I simply searched for online guidance, which is usually super useful on Digital Ocean (DO). This is why I tend to prefer DO over other online premises: it's easy and highly configurable.

An example of how to deal with graphics installation can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-graphical-interface).

Compared with ROS, YARP is a gentler beast, but I can imagine the installation is still doable, even though you would require definitely a droplet with more resources.